# Showing List to Data Grid

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, datagrid

Hi I'm new to Xamarin and currently I have a project that requires me to display something like image below

[image: screenshot]

I already have a list of the items, and inside the list i have another list inside every item that contain "actualwork" and "plannedwork". But i dont know how to present i that way.

So i have a list that contain a list. And i want to display it like in the image. Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <ListView
                Footer=" "
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                HeightRequest="{Binding WeekHeight}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding WeekReports}"
                SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView BackgroundColor="Beige">
                        <Grid Padding="0"
                                HeightRequest="70"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <Label Text="Sun" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Mon" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <Label Text="Tue" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Label Text="Wed" Grid.Column="4"/>
                            <Label Text="Thu" Grid.Column="5"/>
                            <Label Text="Fir" Grid.Column="6"/>
                            <Label Text="Sat" Grid.Column="7"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell IsEnabled="False">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Work}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value1}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value2}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value3}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value4}" Grid.Column="4"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value5}" Grid.Column="5"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value6}" Grid.Column="6"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Value7}" Grid.Column="7"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

ItemSource Model Would be like this:

```
public class Report{        
  public string Work { get; set; }
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
    public string value3 { get; set; }
    public string value4 { get; set; }
    public string value5 { get; set; }
    public string value6 { get; set; }
    public string value7 { get; set; }
}
```